# "Data" — singular or plural

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct?

> The data was kept in soft form.
>   The data were kept in soft form.

Comment: @medica I think you might just be right! I wish we had a less hedged version available for such obvious duplicates.